# how can i get records from wp_postmeta table using particular meta_key in database?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, database

In plugin development, how to fetch data from database of particular data in dropdown list?

```
global $wpdb;
$id = 'parent_id';
$data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = $id"); 
echo $data;
```

i get results as array
how can i get all values in dropdown list?
Can you please help?

Comment: Return data will always be an array. Use print_r()

Comment: @Naresh This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/113264)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            <select name="parent_id" id="parent-id">
                <?php 
                    $sql = "SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='parent_id'";
                    $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());    
                    foreach( $results as $result ) {    
                ?>
                <?php echo $result->meta_value;?>           
                    <option <?php if ($result->meta_value == $parent) echo 'selected="selected" ';?> >
                        <?php //echo $result->meta_value; ?>
                        <?php echo $result->meta_value; ?>
                    </option>
                <?php 
                    }
                ?>                      
            </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to iterate through your array with a for loop and create your own drop down.